# How to read multiple lines input in python

Tags: python, input, raw-input

I am new to Python and I was trying to workout an interviewstreet problem of Kingdom Connectivity. Although, I managed to solve the problem, I'm having trouble giving input of the given format, I've tried my solution on my system and the output is correct, but as soon as I compile there, there is no output.

Input is of the form:

```
5 5
1 2
2 3
3 4
1 3
4 5
```

Please, help me figure out how to solve this problem.

Currently, I'm taking input from `raw_input()` in a loop and splitting using `a.split(' ')`.

Here is part of the question:

```
**Input Description:**

First line contains two integers N and M.

Then follow M lines ,each having two integers say x and y, 1<=x,y<=N , indicating there is a road from city x to city y.

**Output Description:**

Print the number of different paths from city 1 to city N modulo 1,000,000,000(10^9).If there are infinitely many different paths print "INFINITE PATHS"(quotes are for clarity).

**Sample Input:**

5 5
1 2
2 4
2 3
3 4
4 5

**Sample Output:**

2

**Sample Input:**

5 5
1 2
4 2
2 3
3 4
4 5

**Sample Output:**

INFINITE PATHS
```

**Here is my solution**

```
import sys
import numpy as np
c=0
x=raw_input()
y=x.split(' ')
l=(int(y[0]),int(y[1]))
e=[raw_input() for i in range(l[1])]
f=[e[i].split(' ') for i in range(l[1])]
a=[map(int,i) for i in f]
b=[[0 for i in a] for j in range(l[0])]
for i in range(l[0]+1):
    for j in range(l[0]+1):
        if [i,j] in a:
            b[i-1][j-1]=1
        elif a[i-1][0]>=a[i-1][1]:
            print "INFINITE PATHS"
            sys.exit(0)
for i in range(0,l[1]): 
    d=np.linalg.matrix_power(b,i+1)
    c+=d[0][l[1]-1]   
print c
```

Here is screenshot
[image]

Comment: Show us your code so we can see where the error is located.

Comment: Btw -- is this homework? If yes please tag it as such.

Comment: @hochl i have edited and added my code

Comment: in what way is this homework? i have a genuine problem, i am not asking to do my code, i just need help for input part,it would be great if i get help,because in all the other questions,same problem i am facing

Comment: What does "there is no output" mean? Are you sure the problem is with how you do the input?

Comment: @WolframH i am adding an screenshot

Comment: What is your problem? Showvan erroneous session.

Comment: @Marcin problem is the input part,i cant figure out how to take it correctly, i have tried three methods,but all have failed.

Comment: whoever gave you the task, did you ask them how are you supposed to access the input??

Comment: no, it's mentioned in the question,and its a online challenge so it was not given by anybody

Comment: Did you try running your program locally? Did you try debugging it?

Comment: ya,its working perfectly on my system,but i guess the way they analyze input is different,that's why i have no output

Answer (score 3):

I found your program difficult to understand.  So, I rewrote it, and I think my version is a bit easier to understand.

```
import sys
import numpy as np


line = raw_input()
max_val, num_paths = (int(n) for n in line.split())


# a will be a list of tuples of int, taken from the input.
#
# Each tuple represents a path, so this is effectively a sparse representation
# of a square matrix of possible paths.
#
# Input city numbers are 1-based, but we will treat them as 0-based, so
# subtract 1 from each value before appending to array a.

a = []
for _ in xrange(num_paths):
    line = raw_input()

    # TRICKY: subtract 1 to convert from 1-based to 0-based city numbers
    tup = tuple(int(n)-1 for n in line.split())

    if len(tup) != 2:
        raise ValueError, "input should only have two values per line"
    for n in tup:
        if not 0 <= n < max_val:
            raise ValueError, "value must be in range [1, %d]" % max_val
        if tup[0] >= tup[1]:
            #raise ValueError, "INFINITE PATHS"
            print "INFINITE PATHS"
            sys.exit(0)
    a.append(tup)


# Expand the sparse matrix representation into an actual square matrix.
# It should have a 1 anywhere a path was indicated with a tuple in list a,
# and a 0 everywhere else.
b = [ [0 for _ in xrange(max_val)] for _ in xrange(max_val)]
for i, j in a:
    b[i][j] = 1


c = 0
for i in xrange(num_paths):
    d = np.linalg.matrix_power(b, i + 1)
    c += d[0][max_val - 1]
print c
```

My version does print `2` when given the example input.

Here are some things I figured out as I worked on this:

The first line gives us constants (`N` and `M` in the documentation, representing the max legal value and the number of paths respectively).  You should save these values in variables with good names, rather than putting them in a list and referring to them by list index.  I have used the names `max_val` and `num_paths`.  You yourself made a mistake: you are supposed to find paths from city 1 to city N, so the check at the end should be `d[0][max_val - 1]`; you used `l[1]` which is `num_paths` rather than `l[0]`.

`b` should be a square matrix.  Your code was setting the width based on the length of `a`, but `max_val` and `num_paths` might not always be equal, so that's a dangerous way to do it.

It is strange to loop over every possible point in the square matrix and check to see whether it should be set as a 1 or not.  It's also very inefficient, especially because the `in` test is O(n) where n is the length of the array `a`.  Instead, build the empty square matrix, and then simply loop over the paths and set the 1 values per path.

Likewise, it is strange to validate the input values in the loop that initializes the square matrix; it's better to validate the input values as they are read in the input loop.  And again it is dangerous, because `num_paths` might be unrelated to `max_val`.  Also it's inefficient, because you were checking `a[i-1][0]` against `a[i-1][1]` once per column in `b`; that comparison doesn't use the value `j` at all.  You were doing each check five times; it's enough to do each check once.

There is a Python idiom that I used, where you can use `_` (a single underscore) as the name of a variable when you don't care about the value of that variable.  When we are just doing something a certain number of times with a loop, and we won't be using the loop counter value for anything, I used a `_` as the loop counter variable.  This is not essential of course.

To answer your actual question: I don't see any possible way for your program not to produce output.  I suspect that there might be an issue on the server that runs this test problem.  Your program should always either print "INFINITE PATHS" or else some sort of integer value.

P.S. I don't actually understand how your program works; the problem description says you should provide a number of paths modulo 1e9, and I don't see anything to enforce that.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the specified input as follows:

```
line = raw_input()
n, m = map(int, line.split())

for _ in range(m):
  line = raw_input()
  x, y = map(int, line.split())
  print x, y
```

Comment: how to store values of [x,y] in list a..?

Comment: use `a.append([x, y])` (after initializing `a = []` before the loop)

Comment: Isn't this is equivalent to what the OP does?

Comment: i checked just now, it's still not taking input, is there any correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the input in a file input.txt in the same folder as the script:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    l = [int(i) for i in f.readline().split(" ")]
    a = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        a.append([int(i) for i in line.strip().split(" ")])
print(l, a)
```

---

if the input is passed as a command line argument:

```
import sys
input_string = sys.argv[1]
print(input_string) # test if this prints the input
...
```

Comment: @sum2000 if it's not a command line argument nor a file input, i don't think we can figure it out by guessing without asking the task giver / reading all of the instructions

Comment: @deathApril, the problem statement makes it pretty clear: the input is simply the standard input, and sum2000 is correctly using `raw_input()` to read the input.  You can test your input by copying the example numbers from the problem statement, and pasting them into the Python program as it is running; or by putting them in a file and piping the file's contents through to the Python program.